# jdbc4 - how to insert money type?

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc, database-connection

I faced an interesting problem as... I have MSSQL (2005) table A which contains money type column; the thing is I want to insert value to this column with T-SQL procedure call from Java code but I am not pretty sure which Java type should I use to prepare statement for this column to insert value?
I couldn't find any example so maybe you can share some helpful snippets.

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... 
things I could figure out is NOT TO USE money type directly just because the jdbc4 connector PrepareSatement does not contain setMoney etc so I want to share some walk around... Of course, it is not the final code way but still...

So

- A) Money class from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Moneytype.htm) to get string as $00.00 with
  **displayAsDollars** method
- B) create mssql procedure with code like a

  ```
  create procedure aschema.test @a varchar(10)
  AS
  BEGIN

  DECLARE @b money    
  SET @b=CAST @a AS MONEY

  --todo: insert next...

  END;
  ```
- C) So the proc call is quite simple as

  ```
  Money m=new Money("12.99");

  callableStatement = (SQLServerCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(
                          "{call "+
                          DATABASE_NAME+
                          "."+
                          SCHEMA_NAME+
                          ".test(?)}");
  callableStatement.setString(1,m.displayAsDollarsCorrectly());
  callableStatement.executeUpdate();
  ```

  //...

As I was saying it is not the final code decision but a temp conception which may be  helpful as well if you really need to use money type in your old mssql database. At least it was a temp answer in my case :)

I hope it will be helpful for someone :)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a `double` (or maybe `float`, but probably not)? Also, what are you gaining by using `MONEY` in your database? I've found `DECIMAL` to be much more reliable and flexible - for some background see [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and [Performance / Storage Comparisons : MONEY vs. DECIMAL](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal) (sorry for missing images).

Comment: Emm... money type is a usual thing for 00.00 type so I use it in my MSSQL Database... I heard that Java has money type so can it be helpful?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a base type in Java that reflects `MONEY` - at least I don't see any such thing listed here: http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/datatypes.java.php. Anyway to store `00.00`, `MONEY` is *not* "the usual thing" - `DECIMAL` is. Did you read the articles I pointed out?

Comment: There is no primitive type as money, as I could see it, but there a class Money  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Moneytype.htm which contains BigDecimal so maybe it can be helpful then...

Comment: The most problem is I am not sure how to use "Money" object with the MS jdbc4 driver and its PrepareSatement... What should I use as to "set" then? Something like setObject(int,Money)? Because I couldn't find a "setMoney(...)" method there

Comment: @user592704 Why do you need to use MONEY in the database? The links above certainly point out some issues that make me want to re-visit some of my older databases that use MONEY...

Comment: Just because I have already a large db which I want to fill in some new way but not to change col type :)